# Cairo glyph caching

Tags: c, cairo

I'm using Cairo for text rendering on an embedded device. I've evaluated the 'toy' text API (i.e. `cairo_show_text`) and it works very well and is efficient. Unforunately it only supports the most basic operations and always discards the shape immediately.

What I need to do is draw simple text with fill **and** stroke. When I do this using the slightly more complicated API (`cairo_text_path`) it works but performance drops to unacceptable levels.

It's a bit difficult to find documentation but I did find this hint:

> Be aware cairo_show_text() caches glyphs so is much more efficient if you work with a lot of text.

Where can I read about this glyph caching and how to it also for `cairo_text_path`? Ideally, is there a code example of this being done? I only need to support this simple use case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cairo_text_path` converts a text with all glyphs to a path and adds him to the context. Rendering this path is expensive because of many segments - dozens of moves, lines, curves for every single glyph.

Glyphs caching by `cairo_show_text` means that repeating glyphs/characters get rendered once and saved in a much cheaper format (like scanlines, triangles or bitmap) for later occurrences. Because the font doesn't change in-between, this recycling isn't a problem.

You could do this caching by yourself, rendering glyphs on [image surfaces](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-Image-Surfaces.html) and using them as [pattern](http://cairographics.org/manual/cairo-cairo-pattern-t.html#cairo-pattern-create-for-surface), or simply use [bitmap fonts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_font#BITMAP) from the beginning.